# iPhone and iPad apps have gone missing since update

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes-store, applications

When I updated to the most recent iPhone software last year, my phone had trouble getting the update and after resetting it and trying to restore it, I still have a number of apps that I can't find. These apps:

- don't show in my "purchase" list in the iStore
- **do** show as downloaded if I try to repurchase (even the free ones)
- are not hidden
- show as an unchecked app on the list of apps on the left if I open the iPhone in iTunes, but when I check it, it does not allow it to be synched because it says it can't be found

I have an iPhone 3GS and iPad 2 with a MacBook Pro as the mothership. Any way to redownload apps that the store clearly knows I already own (wouldn't label them 'downloaded' if it didn't).

I have checked under my two diff identities (a me.com account and another one that I owned from way back) and have same issue in both.

Answer (score 3):

Apps that have been removed from the App Store can no longer be downloaded, regardless of having been purchased or free. If you can confirm that you cannot find them in the App Store, then, sadly, this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you performed a  backup of your phone prior updating the firmware you can locate the missing apps in  directory "Mobile Applications". Firstly you you have to drag and drop the needed app to your library in iTunes and after that you can drag and drop it from iTunes' Apps to your iPhone.